Chrome extension manifest v3 is commands are not working as expected
I am creating an extension that performs AI search and code snippet execution on https://dsabyte.com from anywhere on the browser. I want my users to open the search box by typing commands on any website. Extension will search the database and will present results to the users on https://dsabyte.com.
But, for some reason, commands are not working, here are the details.
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Ai2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A professional link manager extension",
  "homepage_url": "https://dsabyte.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/favicon-16x16.png",
    "32": "images/favicon-32x32.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/favicon-16x16.png",
      "32": "images/favicon-32x32.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Click Me",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"]
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content/script.js"],
      "css": ["content/style.css"]
    }
  ],
  "commands": {
    "toggle-search": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Space",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Space"
      },
      "description": "Start searching your history"
    }
  }
}

background.js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  console.log(`Command: ${command}`);
});

When i am typing Command+Shift+Space on Mac, it's not working. Then I went to chrome://extensions/shortcuts on the browser and added shortcuts for the extension and it started working.

My question is, do all my users have to follow the same step after installing the extension? Isn’t there any other way so that my users will get this behaviour by default?

It's a bug: https://crbug.com/40923373.
